# SQL GROUP BY with columns which contain mirrored values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate

Sorry for the bad title. I couldn't think of a better way to describe my issue.

I have the following table:

```
Category | A | B
A        | 1 | 2
A        | 2 | 1
B        | 3 | 4
B        | 4 | 3
```

I would like to group the data by `Category`, return only 1 line per category, but provide both values of columns `A` and `B`.

So the result should look like this:

```
category | resultA | resultB
A        | 1       | 2
B        | 4       | 3
```

How can this be achieved?

I tried this statement:

```
SELECT category, a, b
FROM table
GROUP BY category
```

but obviously, I get the following errors:

> Column 'a' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained
> in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Column 'b' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
> aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Can you explain your expected output a little more? why is A = 1, 4 kept and 2, 3 removed? Do you want to keep any one row for each category?

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting which values in a and b you want to display?

Comment: And if there are three rows with A category, with this couple {5, 5} what will be your result?

Comment: "I would like to group the data by Category" - do you really? One result row per category, no matter what values? So far you are only showing data with one attribute pair per category (1 with 2 for A; 3 with 4 for B). Please show more records per category and tell us how this affects expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT category, MIN(a) AS resultA, MAX(a) AS resultB
FROM table
GROUP BY category
```

If the values are mirrored then you can get both values using `MIN`, `MAX` applied on a single column like `a`.

Comment: This won't generate the expected output (which admittedly may not make any sense).

Comment: This is not providing outputs from columns a and b, nor is it solving the issue of which values are returned.

Comment: @Simon Actually, I think this may really be what the OP wants, but it won't match the expected output.

Comment: @Tim the OP states he wants values of A and B, not min and max of A. Either way, I agree it's not going to provide the expected output.

Comment: @Tim I agree, this is what I had in mind when I wrote the post. I think the OP actually doesn't care about the order between the two fields.

Comment: OP here. then min/max combination actually is what I desire. I ensure with another query, that not more than two entries are available per category. hence min/max will always catch both values and yield the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Seams you don't really want to aggregate per category, but rather remove duplicate rows from your result (or rather rows that you consider duplicates).

You consider a pair (x,y) equal to the pair (y,x). To find duplicates, you can put the lower value in the first place and the greater in the second and then apply `DISTINCT` on the rows:

```
select distinct
  category,
  case when a < b then a else b end as attr1,
  case when a < b then b else a end as attr2
from mytable;
```

Comment: Interesting logic switch, but would return non-mirrored as well

Answer (score 2):

Considering you want a random record from duplicates for each `category`.

Here is one trick using table valued constructor and `Row_Number` window function

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT *,
       (SELECT Min(min_val) FROM (VALUES (a),(b))tc(min_val)) min_val,
       (SELECT Max(max_val) FROM (VALUES (a),(b))tc(max_val)) max_val
FROM   (VALUES ('A',1,2),
               ('A',2,1),
               ('B',3,4),
               ('B',4,3)) tc(Category, A, B) 
)
select Category,A,B from 
(
Select Row_Number()Over(Partition by category,max_val,max_val order by (select NULL)) as Rn,*
From cte
) A
Where Rn = 1
```