# SQL GROUP BY with columns which should contain mirrored values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate

Sorry for the bad title. I couldn't think of a better way to describe my issue.

I have the following table:

```
Category | A | B
A        | 1 | 2
A        | 2 | 2
B        | 3 | 4
B        | 4 | 3
```

The values of category A (lines 1 and 2) are wrong, because columns A and B should be mirrored. For category B (lines 3 and 4) the values are correct.

This is what the correct table should look like:

```
Category | A | B
A        | 1 | 2
A        | 2 | 1
B        | 3 | 4
B        | 4 | 3
```

However, I have the first table at hand. And for this table I want to output an error message stating that values 1 and 2 are not correctly `mirrored`.

To create this output message, I use the following query

```
SELECT 'The values of category ' + category + ' are not correctly mirrored'
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.category=t2.category AND t1.A!=t2.A AND (t1.A!=t2.B OR t1.B!=t2.A)
GROUP BY t1.category
```

This query works. However, I would like to enhance the error message with the respective values of A and B. Something like:

```
SELECT 'The values ' + a + ' and ' + b + ' of category ' + category + ' are not correctly mirrored'
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.category=t2.category AND t1.A!=t2.A AND (t1.A!=t2.B OR t1.B!=t2.A)
GROUP BY t1.category
```

But then I, obviously, get the following error:

> Column 'a' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained
> in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Column 'b' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
> aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL GROUP BY with columns which contain mirrored values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026970/sql-group-by-with-columns-which-contain-mirrored-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT Category,
       CASE
         WHEN Min(A) = Min(B)
              AND Max(A) = Max(B) THEN 'The values of category ' + category + ' are correctly mirrored'
         ELSE 'The values of category ' + category + ' are not correctly mirrored'
       END
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY Category
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the group by condition and select the top 1 row so you can show the values of a and b.

```
SELECT TOP 1
        'The values ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), t1.a) + ' and ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), t1.b) + ' of category ' + t1.category + ' are not correctly mirrored' ErrMessage
    FROM [table] t1
        INNER JOIN [table] t2 ON t1.category=t2.category AND t1.A!=t2.A AND (t1.A!=t2.B OR t1.B!=t2.A)
    ORDER BY
        t1.category
        ,t1.a
        ,t1.b
```

or you can count the results with ROW_NUMBER and making a PARTITION BY category if you are expecting more than one category with similar error.

```
SELECT
        A.ErrMessage
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
                'The values ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), t1.a) + ' and ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), t1.b) + ' of category ' + t1.category + ' are not correctly mirrored' ErrMessage
                ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t1.category ORDER BY t1.a, t1.B) Position
            FROM [table] t1
                INNER JOIN [table] t2 ON t1.category=t2.category AND t1.A!=t2.A AND (t1.A!=t2.B OR t1.B!=t2.A)
    ) A
    WHERE A.Position = 1
```

That last for example for a table like this:

```
Category A           B
-------- ----------- -----------
A        1           2
A        2           2
B        3           4
B        4           3
C        5           6
C        6           6
```

Will return the two categories with error:

```
ErrMessage
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
The values 1 and 2 of category A are not correctly mirrored
The values 5 and 6 of category C are not correctly mirrored
```